# How to set a default Profile in the User object?

Tags: profile, user

I'm setting up a process which will automatically create new Users, but need to set ProfileID to something. I can't use Process Builder because it's a required field and it would error out before it got to the Process, even if it's set to run on create.

It's an Informatica upsert function running off a list of employees. I can't hard code the profile ID into the Informatica task because some of the employess are already created and therefore already have assigned profiles.

The Profile I want to use is a custom profile. I don't think that matters, but I thought I'd mention it.

my current code (thank you @adrian) :

```
trigger AssignDefaultProfile on User (before insert) {

    static Profile fallbackProfile
        {
            get
                {
                    if (fallbackProfile == null)
                        fallbackProfile = [SELECT id FROM Profile p WHERE p.Name = 'Service Employee'] ; 
                    return fallbackProfile;
                }
            private set;
        }

    public static void setFallbackProfile(List<User> users)  
        {
            for (User user : users)
                if (user.ProfileId == null)
                    user.ProfileId = fallbackProfile.Id;
        }

    static UserRole fallbackRole
        {
            get
                {
                    if (fallbackRole == null)
                        fallbackRole = [SELECT id FROM UserRole r WHERE r.Name = 'General Employee'] ; 
                    return fallbackRole;
                }
            private set;
        }

    public static void setFallbackRole(List<User> users)
        {
            for (User user : users)
                if (user.UserRoleId == null)
                    user.UserRoleId = fallbackRole.Id;
        }
}
```

Comment: That is not how triggers work...

Comment: Can you be a more specific please ?

Comment: See my updated answer. You don't add methods to a trigger, you add them to a class and call them from a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simple enough to create a `User` trigger that sets the `ProfileId` value to your fallback if it is blank. Something along the lines of:

```
static Profile fallbackProfile
{
    get
    {
        if (fallbackProfile == null)
            fallbackProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE ...];
        return fallbackProfile;
    }
    private set;
}
public static void setFallbackProfile(List<User> users)
{
    for (User user : users)
        if (user.ProfileId == null)
            user.ProfileId = fallbackProfile.Id;
}
```

Just call the above in a `before insert` trigger on the `User` object and you should be good to go.

If you want to add a fallback `UserRole` as well, it would look something like:

```
static UserRole fallbackRole
{
    get
    {
        if (fallbackRole == null)
            fallbackRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE ...];
        return fallbackRole;
    }
    private set;
}
public static void setFallbackProfile(List<User> users)
{
    for (User user : users)
        if (user.UserRoleId == null)
            user.UserRoleId = fallbackRole.Id;
}
```

Best to keep the methods separate, since you don't want to populate the role just because the profile is blank, or vice versa.

Once you've added these methods to an `Apex Class` (I would call it `UserService`), you can reference them from your `Apex Trigger`.

```
trigger User on User (before insert)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            UserService.setFallbackProfile(trigger.new);
            UserService.setFallbackRole(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

I highly recommend you look into trigger handler patterns and adopt one, the above is just to give you the idea.

Comment: Adrian - thank you very much. That's definitely the solution, even if it's not a non-code solution. Another part I forgot about was the Role which is also required. I attempted to add it to your code but I'm getting different errors. I put my edited version in my original post. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong with the Role ?  As of now I'm getting a 'Variable does not exist : user.Role' error, but I'm guessing there's others as well.

Comment: Doesn't look like you did edit your post. Anyway, the field you need to set is `UserRoleId`. Make sure you populate it with the Id of a `UserRole`, not the record itself.

Comment: @Zoom do ***not*** use hard-coded ids! That defeats the whole purpose of performing the query. Filter based on `DeveloperName` for `UserRole`, and `Name` for `Profile`.

Comment: Ok yes, that was pretty stupid to use IDs. I edited it again. Can you see the edit now ?

Comment: My guess was correct, the field you need to populate is `UserRoleId`, not `Role`. Also note that when you do not use brackets after an `if` statement, only the next statement is "bracketed", so your role assignment takes place unconditionally as written.

Comment: I am attempting to test this by manually creating a User without entering a Role or a Profile, but the required field flags are still happening. Should this work with a UI entry or only through a back-end creation ? I updated my above code to show what I have now.  Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: @zoom did you actually create the before insert trigger?

Comment: Yes -  and it's active.

Comment: I ran the back-end creation Informatica process and it's not populating the fields either. I still get the errors saying the required ProfileID field is blank. I can't believe we can't just set a default profile.